# Modal dont close

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with close a modal, 
i check for jquery and its ok.

I am using 1.12.4 version and i have tag in head of code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My open modal tag is:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" class="modal-trigger" data-id="11" href="#komentarM"></a>
```

And my modal cocde is:

```
<div id="komentarM" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Modal Header</h4>
        <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="id" value=""></input>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this code i try trigger showing a modal:

```
<script>
```

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$('#komentarM').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    data = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id')
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="id"]').val(data);
});
```

});

Problem is when i click to close modal, or click on black spaces on page my modal was closed but when i click to open modal again only overlay show.
I am post a picture what happens when i close modal and open again.

[image]

Comment: Did you check if there's an [error] when you've open your [console] once you've click that certain [button] that opens your [modal]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in closing modal, modal was close but not in code, when i try open again that start break and i am add in jq:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.lean-overlay', function () {
$('.modal').modal('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the chrome/firefox error console ? I think it will be throwing some js error when it is trying to reopen the modal. Reason is  could be the re-execution of following code on reopening. I may not be correct with below code but some error must be being recorded in console which will help in debugging

```
$('#komentarM').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
data = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id')
$(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="id"]').val(data);
});
```

If no error is being thrown in console then i recommend try changing the jquery library to next stable version and make sure it is compatible with bootstrap framework. just a suggestion to debug

if you do not use shown event then does it work (modal gets reopened)?

[modified sample]

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script
   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"
   integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU="
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css     " rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-     BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"      crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"      integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="komentarM" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
    <p>A bunch of text</p>
</div>
<input type="text" name="id" value=""></input>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
     </div>
 </div>
 <a data-toggle="modal" class="modal-trigger" data-id="11"      href="#komentarM">Hello</a>

 </body>
 <script> 
 $(document).ready(function () {

 $('#komentarM').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
     data = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id')
     $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="id"]').val(data);
     });
 });

</script>
```

Comment: Hello, i dont have any error in console log, if i call modal first time its works and i can close it but when i call secound time its not work exmp is picture,

Comment: I have copied the code you have given and created a sample one and modal is getting poped up every time I click on link without any error. That means there is some issue in the other part of code which has been not shared(other css, javasscript plugin or theme which you are using if any). I recommend you debug it in chrome and check when you click the link for opening modal then in code does it is adding "modal-open" (for example in code below I get <body class="modal-open"> so check for "modal-open" and if it is appearing then it means there can be some CSS issue. I have edited sample above

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a semicolon at line:2

```js
$('#komentarM').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    data = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="id"]').val(data);
});
```